# Distribution of synapses of CA1 neurons

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology

In the Wikipedia article on [dendritic spikes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendritic_spike#Spatial_Summation) I read:

> In the hippocampus, the CA1 neurons contain two distinctive regions
>   that receive excitatory synaptic inputs: the perforant path (PP)
>   through the apical dendritic tuft (500-750 μm from soma) and the
>   Schaffer-collateral (SC) through the basal and apical dendrites
>   (250-500 μm from soma).

I wonder how the distinctiveness of these two regions does appear when plotting the number of synapses as a function of the distance to the soma:

[image]

More like the gray, or more like the red, or more like the green curve? Or which other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One source for this estimate is [Megias et al. 2001](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0306452200004966/1-s2.0-S0306452200004966-main.pdf?_tid=4cc77394-a8fc-11e7-8af5-00000aab0f02&acdnat=1507118903_e44fe00da64abc293794a2b05c7d26d1), an electron microscopy study in CA1 of the rat hippocampus.

I plot their data from Table 3 in the following graph.
[image: Total synapse number per dendritic subclass, based on Megias et al. 2001]

The X-axis is not in micrometers. Rather it represents dendritic subclasses. $Ori$ stands for Stratum Oriens, $Rad$ for S. Radiatum, $L-M$ for Lacunosum-Moleculare, $T$ for thick dendrites, $t$ for thin dendrites, $prox/med/dist$ for proximal, medial, and distal, respectively. Stratum Oriens represents basal dendrites that are close to the cell body, stratum Radiatum apical trunks, and stratum Lacunosum-Moleculare the apical tufts. The approximate locations of the layers in reference to the cell body are (in micrometers): $Ori = (-100, 0)$, $Rad = (100, 350)$, $L-M = (350,550)$. The Y-axis represents the total number of synapses, both excitatory and inhibitory.

Comment: Isn't it possible to attach rough distances to the dendritic subclasses? Since distance to the soma **is** important.

Comment: What does a  negative distance mean?

Comment: If we assign the cell body, or more precisely the stratum pyramidale, at $0$, then stratum oriens is to its dorsal side and stratum radiatum on its ventral side. I've arbitrarily assigned dorsal $\rightarrow$ ventral as the positive direction.

Comment: But the effective (physical) distance is still positive, isn't it?

Comment: How could the soma distinguish between dorsal and ventral?

Comment: I have included direction to help the reader realize where the cell body would lie in the above bar graph, nothing more.